# SortableMixin doesn't sort when using a custom transform

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I decided to use UTC dates in my Ember app so by following the recommendation [here](http://blog.skylight.io/bringing-sanity-to-javascript-utc-dates-with-moment-js-and-ember-data/) I created the following transform:

**app/transforms/utc.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Transform.extend({  
    serialize: function(value) {
        return value ? value.toJSON() : null;
    },

    deserialize: function(value) {
        return moment.utc(value);
    }
});
```

I then used it in my model:

**app/models/payment.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    student: DS.belongsTo('student'),

    date: DS.attr('utc'),
    amount: DS.attr('number'),

    formattedDate: function() {
        var date = this.get('date');
        return moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    }.property('date')
});
```

Before using the `utc` transform I was able to sort the payments by using this function:

```
payments: (function() {
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
        sortProperties: ['date'],
        sortAscending: false,
        content: this.get('content.payments')
    });
}).property('content.payments'),
```

Now, after using the `utc` transform, the above function doesn't work anymore. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because moment doesn't give you date objects, it gives you a special moment object. Normally, this wouldn't matter since moment gives those objects a `valueOf` method which will satisfy the built-in Javascript comparison operators. Ember, however, uses a [custom sort function](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_compare). [Looking at the source code for Ember.compare](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/compare.js#L20), we can see that there's a specific path for Javascript date objects, but for normal Javascript objects it always returns 0 (sorted equally).

Long story short, use a compare function instead of the compare property name (using the built-in Javascript comparison operators):

```
sortFunction: function(a, b) {
    return (a < b ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Comment: how could I override the default sortFunction inside my object which I extend with Ember.SortableMixin?

Comment: Exactly how I have it above. Just declare a `sortFunction` method on the object.